# An algebraic inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, uvw

> Let $a,b,c$  be real numbers with $a+b+c=0$.
>    I want to show that 
>   $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+3 \geq 6abc$$

Comment: & you have tried ... ?

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: This inequality was on one of Polish contests.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Since, $a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2=9v^4-6uw^3$, we see that our inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$,

which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for an extremal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$ and $c=-2a$.

Hence, we need to prove that:
$$3a^4-4a^3+1\geq0,$$
which is AM-GM:
$$3a^4+1\geq4\sqrt[4]{(a^4)^3\cdot1}=4|a^3|\geq4a^3.$$
Done!

Another way.

Since $a+b+c=0$, we can assume $c\leq0$. Let $ab=x$.

Thus, $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=c^2-2x$ and we need to prove that
$$x^2-2(c^2+3c)x+c^4+3\geq0$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$(c^4+3c)^2-(c^4+3)\leq0$$ or
$$(c+1)^2(2c-1)\leq0.$$
Done!

Comment: for your second way Michael, what happens if $$a\le 0,b\le0$$ and $$c\geq 0$$?

Comment: the case that $$c\le 0,b\geq0,a\geq 0$$ is easy

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner $a+b+c=0$. If $a>0$, $b>0$ and $c>0$ then we have contradiction. Thus, one of them less or equal to zero. Since our inequality is symmetric, we can assume that $c\leq0$.

Comment: this is clear but it can be $$a\le 0,b\le 0$$ and $$c\geq 0$$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner If $a\leq0$, $b\leq0$ and $c\geq0$ we 'll take $bc=x$ and the rest is the same.

Comment: ok i see it now thank you Michael